# Angular 2 project not running on some computers

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 project that works perfectly fine on my machine as well as one of my coworkers, however two of my other coworkers can't get the project running. They have the proper Node, NPM, and TypeScript versions and are able to get the Angular 2 Quickstart project running fine, but for whatever reason, when they run `npm start` on my project, the loading screen comes up and just gets stuck there. No errors in the browser console, however when they run `npm start`, they do get 404s on .map files inside node_module/systemjs/*. These errors do not happen on my machine, in fact I don't see any evidence that my machine is even looking for those files when I start the project. To get rid of those error messages, he said he deleted the angular.min.js.map file, but it didn't fix the problem of the app not loading.

I am completely at a loss here. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Here is our **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.40.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Here is our **systemjs.config** file:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'angular2-jwt':              'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
            'fullcalendar':              'npm:fullcalendar',
            'primeng':                   'npm:primeng',
            'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js'  // For address autocomplete
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-jwt': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

We are running TypeScript 2.0, npm 3.10.10, and node 6.9.4

Comment: try npm run start. but you already said the node, npm and typescript are same version. just try

Comment: if you can create a plunker

Comment: What platform (OS) do you use ? Are they any errors on node console ? If yes, can you try separately to see what made an error :  npm run tsc, npm run lite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with our environments. The latest version of Angular 2's router (3.4.8) has issues, which you can read about here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14588

The solution, until Angular fixes the bug(s), is to lock in your router at version 3.4.7. For anyone who is having the same issue, change package.json to: `"@angular/router": "3.4.7",`